# Create trigger raises exception

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger before insert on a table.

It checks the specific value if it is not valid it will raise an exception

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_birthdate
      BEFORE INSERT ON student 

DECLARE 
     invalid_date EXCEPTION ;
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.birthdate >= sysdate - interval '16' year )
    THEN RAISE invalid_date ;
    END IF ;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN invalid_date THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'AGE MUST BE GREATER THAN 16 !!');
END;
/
```

it does not work.

This the output, any help ?

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL>
SQL> show errors
Errors for TRIGGER INSERT_BIRTHDATE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------
4/2      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
4/8      PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.BIRTHDATE' must be declared
SQL>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line

```
IF(NEW.birthdate >= sysdate - interval '16' year )
```

with

```
IF(:NEW.birthdate >= sysdate - interval '16' year )
```

Also, you need to execute the before trigger for each row instead of the whole statement .

From the Docs,

In a BEFORE statement trigger, the trigger body cannot read :NEW or :OLD. (In a BEFORE row trigger, the trigger body can read and write the :OLD and :NEW fields.)

So like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT
   ON student
   FOR EACH ROW
```